# Fullcalendar --> Send selected year

Tags: fullcalendar

i use fullcalendar and want to send the year **of the selected view** (not the current view) to the page "ajax_load_projektkalender.php".

The following try results in an error:

```
events: {
    url: 'ajax_load_projektkalender.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: function() { // a function that returns an object
        return {
            projekte_key: $('#projekte_key').val(),
            aufgaben_key: $('#aufgaben_key').val(),
            sel_year: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.format('Y'),
            urlaub_key: $('#urlaub_key').val(),
            termine_key: $('#termine_key').val()+'',
            gruppiert_key: $('#gruppiert_key').val(),
            bdauer_key: $('#bdauer_key').val()
        };
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
    },
    color: 'yellow',   // a non-ajax option
    textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
}
```

Error: TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar(...).start is null
[Weitere Informationen]

I' m helpless... can anybody give me advice ?

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

You have a bootstrap problem: you define the events of your calendar by referencing the current view, but that will be empty until you have defined the events of your calendar... To break the loop, assuming that initially you want to display the current year, you could write something like:

```
data: function() {
  var current = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').intervalStart
  var y = (current?current:moment()).format('Y')
  return {
    ...
    sel_year: y,
    ...
  }
```

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but actually I suspect you don't need that at all, as fullcalendar automatically adds to the ajax request to your php server a parameter "start" holding the start date of the period to display in ISO format (and similarly an "end" parameter). You can even give an alternative names to your parameters using e.g.

```
startParam: 'Anfang'
```

in your calendar objet.

Answer (score 0):

Try intervalStart instead of start. That should fix the error, but I am not sure it solves your problem.